# where is oracle session timezone set?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a logging table

```
CREATE TABLE EMAIL_LOGGING
(
  ID               NUMBER(9)                    NOT NULL,
  SEND_DATE        TIMESTAMP(6)                 DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP        NOT NULL,
  SEND_TO_USER_ID  NUMBER(9)                    NOT NULL);
```

and a package that inserts into it with this fragment:

```
  INSERT INTO EMAIL_LOGGING ("ID",SEND_DATE, SEND_TO_USER_ID)
       VALUES (NULL, LOCALTIMESTAMP,send_to_user_in);
```

When this is called from a DBMS_JOB from one package it inserts Greenwich mean time.  When it is called from a DBMS_JOB from another package that uses a db_link to another database it correctly inserts the local time.

I think this is caused by the client's timezone being used but adding this to the job did not resolve it:

```
execute immediate 'alter session set time_zone=local';
```

Of course the best solution is to move to DBMS_Scheduler but until that is done how can I ensure that the timestamp that is inserted is the local time?

```
select * from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%';
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
+00:00
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;
-04:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting this attribute

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute (
    attribute => 'default_timezone',
    value     => 'EST');
END;
```

and moving the job to DBMS_SCHEDULER.  Now, when it runs the correct (local) time is entered in the logging table.

Comment: +1 for finding your own answer and giving enough time for others to answer (which no one else did).

Comment: I think I got burned by this setting once before.  If you set it to `EST`, it might get off by one hour when switching to Daylight time.  I tend to set my databases to `dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('DEFAULT_TIMEZONE','America/New_York');`  The three-letter timezones, such as `EST` are deprecated.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html#threeletter

Comment: @JoshuaHuber Thanks, that is correct for Java and Oracle databases, no more three letter abbreviations, use 'America/New_York' http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#NLSPG0141